# react.js dispatch and perform actions synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react.js project I need to perform 2 ajax actions synchronously, one after another. Currently I have a table of users. So I need to delete 1 user (with ajax call) and when that ajax is done, I need to send another one to get updated tabe of users. The code so far:

```
 onOk() {
            that.props
                .removeUser(record.id)
                .then(that.props.getAllUsers());
        }
```

_delete() function in useraction:

```
function _delete(id) {

return  dispatch => {
  dispatch(request(id));
  try{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      userService.delete(id).then(
        () => {
          return resolve(dispatch(success(id)));
        },
        error => {
          return reject(dispatch(failure(id, error)));
        }
    )
  });
 }catch(err){
  dispatch(failure(id, err))
  return Promise.reject();
 }
};
```

userservice delete fn:

```
function _delete(id) {
  return axiosInstance
  .delete(`/users/${id}`)
  .then(handleResponse);
}
```

The problem is that in waterfall section on browser I see that these 2 ajax calls are made in the same time, not one after another.

[image: waterfall pic]

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Small tip: it looks like `userService.delete(id)` already returns a Promise, so the `new Promise` and the try/catch are unnecessary.

Comment: tried to remove `new Promise`, got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Try/catch is unnecessary. Also the reason you get the error when you remove new Promise() is because `_delete` does not `return dispatch( ... `. If you review [thunk composition](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition) it shows a few different approaches to composing promises.

Comment: You should still `return userService.delete(id)` so that `onOk` function can use `then` on `that.props.removeUser(record.id)`

Comment: Also, `then` takes a function, but in `onOk`, you've just put an expression directly instead. Do this instead `.then(() => this.props.getAllUsers())`

Comment: that helped, thank you